# How to deal with conflicting eslint rules in AirBNB configuration

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

I'm a noob trying to write a POC in Vue. I'm using ESLint with the AirBNB configuration, and am running into a conflict.

Here is the error catching part of my Axios call:

```
  .catch((error) => {
    errorMsg.value = error;
    console.log('Error is ' + error);
    console.log(`Error is {error}`);
  });
```

And here is the linter errors I am receiving:

```
  50:21  error  Unexpected string concatenation  prefer-template
  51:21  error  Strings must use singlequote     quotes

✖ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings)
```

Because of these two conflicting rules, it appears I cannot get the output I want. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to replace `{error}` by `${error}`, which is the correct syntax fro string interpolation in JS (ie dont forget the $ sign). ESlint probably thinks that it's a normal string and recommends single quotes

Comment: @Riron: Yup, python tripping me up here. Put it as an answer and I'll mark it correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String interpolation in JS requires a `$` sign.
So you should be using:

```
.catch((error) => {
    errorMsg.value = error;
    console.log('Error without interpolation'); // Single quotes for simple strings
    console.log(`Error is ${error}`); // Template for interpolation
  });
```